# How to vertical and horizontally center prime ng form?

Tags: css, angular, flexbox, primeng

I am using prime ng 9.1.3 and primeflex 1.3.0. I am using p-align-center. But I am unable to vertical and horizontal center the form. I use 100vh for full screen height.

```
<div class="p-grid p-align-center" style="height: 100vh">
  <div class="p-col-6" style="text-align: center"> 
    <h2>Sample app</h2>
  </div>

  <div class="p-col-6" style="background-color: #f1f1f2; height: 100%;">
    <div>
      <form>
        <h4>LOGIN</h4>

        <!--Email Starts-->

        <span class="ui-float-label">
          <input id="float-input" type="email" size="50" pInputText />
          <label for="float-input">Email</label>
        </span>

        <!--Email Ends-->

        <div style="margin-top: 25px"></div>

        <!--Password Starts-->

        <span class="ui-float-label">
          <input id="float-input" type="password" size="50" pInputText />
          <label for="float-input">Password</label>
        </span>

        <!--Password Ends-->

        <div style="margin-top: 25px"></div>

        <p-button label="Login" styleClass="ui-button-success"></p-button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the screen.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try to make the second column with `display:flex` and then align the elements inside it:

```
/* Of course, you need to use a different selector,
   since you don't want to apply these styles to all elements with this class */
.p-col-6 {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Dimitar Spassov. It helps. But the page is not responsive. How can we make the page responsive?

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve when you say responsive? I guess you mean you want to have two columns on wider screens and to make them full-width on smaller screens, right?

Comment: Yes. Dimitar Spassov.

Comment: I think the best way to do this is to get familiar with the PrimeNG grid docs first - please see the `Responsive` section in [the docs page](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/primeflex/grid). In general, if you update the column classes to `p-col-12 p-lg-6`, it will make your layout responsive with two columns on wider screens and full-width columns on smaller ones.